# Tkinter Gui linking button to .py file to open another Gui

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Good Evening!  I am trying to figure out how to get a button to, when clicked, open up another Gui in another .py file that is in the same file folder. (I have tried every answer given in other questions that remotely might answer this for me).

```
enter code here
#this file is called main.py    
from tkinter import *

root1 = Tk()
root1.title("ProQA-ish")


fphoto = PhotoImage(file="../icon/fireorig.png") #change wd to file named icon
fireButton = Button(root1, image=fphoto)
fireButton.config( height=228, width=200)
mphoto = PhotoImage(file="../icon/ems.png")  #change wd to file named icon
emsButton = Button(root1, image=mphoto)
emsButton.config( height=224, width=197)
fireButton.pack(side=LEFT)
emsButton.pack(side=RIGHT)


root1.mainloop()

enter code here
#this is called emdmenu.py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Emergency Medical Dispatch")
root.iconbitmap(default='../icon/fire.ico')
#----Window------

topframe = Frame(root)
topframe.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

#---Create Buttons for choices----
abdominalPnB = Button(topframe, text="01_Abdominal Pain")
abdominalPnB.config(anchor="w", width=20, height=1)
abdominalPnB.grid(row=0, column=0)


allergyrxB = Button(topframe, text="02_Allergic Reaction")
allergyrxB.config(anchor="w", width=20, height=1)
allergyrxB.grid(row=1, column=0)
#ect..

root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import that other .py file into your current one

Do this just like any other module.  `import myfile.py`

create another tkinter function in the external script

link the button to the function in the external script.

The button links with the `command` key. so it should look like:

```
but = Button(bottom, text='click me', command=do_something)
```

In this example `do_something` is the name of the other function. It is weird here you dont actually put `()` into the `command` argument. But `do_something()` is a normal funciton

**EDIT**
Looking at your code and reading your comments I think that what your missing is the concept of creating and calling functions. Your code in the external file is executing first because when you import something it is ran. To avoid this put the code inside a funtion.

In your external file you should have something like this:

```
def func_name():
    print('hello world')
```

Then in your main file the button should have:

`command=func_name`

Comment: Thanks for the response! Just so I have an understanding. I would put import emdmenu.py under the import tkinter and then the button I want to press and have bring up the other file i just put command=emdmenu.py , right? (currently when i do that it brings up the emdmenu.py first and when I close that window it pops up with the one I want to start on)

Comment: No it should be `command=function_Name` the function your calling should be in function form. Any code imported executes on import so check the file that you are importing and make sure all of the logic is inside a function

Comment: I highly recommend thenewboston. They have a website and youtube channel. There is an entire series on tkinter you may find useful

Comment: Awesome thank you! I will try that tomorrow while at work. That makes more sense.